# Replace some objects and arrays using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reduce

I am using nodejs as server side, i got some of the json objects

This is my json array with objects

```
[
    {
        "id": 20,
        "gsm": "123456789",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "contactgroups": [
            {
                "contactId": 20,
                "groupId": 14,
                "group": {
                    "groupname": "Angular"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "gsm": "987654321",
        "firstName": "Ganesh",
        "lastName": "Pandiyan",
        "contactgroups": [
            {

                "contactId": 21,
                "groupId": 14,
                "group": {
                    "groupname": "Angular"
                }
            },
            {
                "contactId": 21,
                "groupId": 15,
                "group": {
                    "groupname": "React"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want final output like this(See my groupname key):

```
[
    {
        "id": 20,
        "gsm": "123456789",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "contactgroups": [
            {
                "contactId": 20,
                "groupId": 14,
                "groupname": "Angular",
                "group": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "gsm": "987654321",
        "firstName": "Ganesh",
        "lastName": "Pandiyan",
        "contactgroups": [
            {

                "contactId": 21,
                "groupId": 14,
                "groupname": "Angular",
                "group": {}
            },
            {
                "contactId": 21,
                "groupId": 15,
                "groupname": "React",
                "group": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

is it possible? to do, which is best map or reduce or lodash? any method?

I want to change the place of groupname and to remove the groupname from group object.

Comment: It is better to explain in words than dumping two big json contents.

Comment: i want to change place of groupname which is in first json, i want like second json

Comment: @MohamedSameer You basically keep asking the same question, apparently without learning anything from previous answers. Like the last time, this is very basic restructuring, and can be done using `forEach`.

Comment: Loop over the array. For each object, loop over the contactgroups array.For each contact, add the groupname property to the contact and set its value to the value inside group.groupname. Overwrite the group proeprty with n empty object. A simple `forEach()` or `.map()` will suffice.

Comment: @ChrisG post some piece of code? i am struggling, sure i am a beginner to programming, will speedup soon

Comment: @MohamedSameer In that case it's too early to post here. At least show what you've tried, and describe how it failed. Don't just wait for people to hand you the (extremely basic) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This will return a new array with modified keys & values

```js
var orgArray = [{
    "id": 20,
    "gsm": "123456789",
    "firstName": "Mohamed",
    "lastName": "Sameer",
    "contactgroups": [{
      "contactId": 20,
      "groupId": 14,
      "group": {
        "groupname": "Angular"
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "gsm": "987654321",
    "firstName": "Ganesh",
    "lastName": "Pandiyan",
    "contactgroups": [{
        "contactId": 21,
        "groupId": 14,
        "group": {
          "groupname": "Angular"
        }
      },
      {
        "contactId": 21,
        "groupId": 15,
        "group": {
          "groupname": "React"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
var newArray = orgArray.map(function(item) {
  return {
    "id": item.id,
    "gsm": item.gsm,
    "firstName": item.firstName,
    "lastName": item.lastName,
     // an IIFE which will create the new contactgroups
    "contactgroups": (function() {
      return item.contactgroups.map(function(item2, index) {
        return {
          "contactId": item2.contactId,
          "groupId": item2.groupId,
          "groupname": item2.group.groupname,
          "group": {}
        }

      })

    }())
  }
})
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: @MohamedSameer I have updated the code. Please verify